# Automatically add hotplug network interface to bridge

Tags: raspbian, ethernet-port, bridge, hot-plug

I have my Pi Zero W set up as a wireless bridge, bridging from wired `eth0` to wireless `wlan0`; of course, wlan0 operates in AP mode. So far so good. Now I'm noticing that when I forgot to plug in the USB Ethernet adapter for `eth0` into my Pi Zero W before boot, it won't be added as a bridge port to my bridge `br0` automatically. How can I ensure that `eth0` always gets added to the bridge, even if I plug `eth0` into the Pi only later?

My `/etc/network/interfaces` has to say this:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
...

auto br0
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
...
```

When I hot-plug `eth0` then `brctl show` only shows `wlan0` for `br0`, but not `eth0`.

Comment: what happens if you plug in eth0 and bring down and back up br0?

Comment: Didn't try; but as I could manually add `eth0` later, I tried an `up` declaration in `/etc/network/interfaces` which worked. So I probably found the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it occured to me that telling `/etc/network/interfaces` to "manually" add the network interface `eth0` to my `br0` bridge may answer my question: yes, indeed, this works. So my `/etc/network/interfaces` contains this:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
...
up brctl addif br0 eth0
```

After quite some testing by pulling eth0 and later hot-plugging it back again I could successfully verify that this works in fact reliably.

Comment: Generic hint: You may want to suffix the up commands with "|| true" so that they don't fail if the command fails.